# ...do as the Romans do

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, letters

## When in Rome, do as the Romans do...

[image: Roman numeral-based puzzle, contained fully in this image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is:

> SEPTENATE
>  A word meaning 'having seven parts'.

This puzzle is indeed composed of things having

> seven parts!

> The Gray boxes list things coming in sets of seven:
>  DWARFS, DEADLY SINS, RAINBOW, PLEIADES, SAMURAI, MAGNIFICENT, TAXONOMY
>  (Nice, there are seven!) We get these by finding words to fill in the top blanks.

The lists in each gray box are the items in the

> Set of seven.
>  Items containing a letter that is a Roman numeral are marked by '?', and appear shuffled in the box to the left. Items that do not are marked by blanks indicating their length.
>  (From OP: It is also noteworthy that the Roman numerals themselves, IVXCLDM, are a set of seven)

> Writing out all the elements in these (details listed at the end of this post), we can then count the number of letters in the final list to find the answers to the boxes for a - k.
>  For example, there are 11 H's, so a = 11-3 = 8, = the letter 'H'.
>  Continuing we get:
>    11 H’s : A = 8: H
>  37 E’s: B = 36/4 = 9 = I
>  10 P’s: C = 10+12 = 12= L
>  12 T’s: D = 12 = L
>  E = 19 = S
>  F = 37-7 = 30 / 2 = 10 = O
>  G = 10-4=6 = F
>  H = 18 = R
>  I = 11 + 4 = 15 = O
>  J = 37+2 = 39 / 3 = 13 = M
>  K = 10/2 = 5 = E
>  (As an aside, the letters which are summed spell HEPT... interesting...).

This spells out:

> HILLS OF ROME!

Moving on to the bottom, we can fill in the

> set of seven with the seven hills of Rome:
>  [image: hills of Rome]

> The order is found by noting that letters marked '#' are Roman numerals.
>  Having highlighted the hexagon-marked spots in bold, this spells out the final answer:

> **SEPTENATE** !

> Here is the final list of words to fill in all of the blanks as it seemed a bit much to put in the explanation above. The ones without Roman numerals are listed in CAPS and appear in the gray box in the order given.
>  The ones in parenthesis go in the large white box to the left. All spaces are used, but it turns out the order doesn't matter to the solution so I will skip that. In general it seems the lists are alphabetical.

> **DWARFS**
>  (Seven dwarfs)
>  HAPPY
>  SNEEZY
>  (bashful, doc, dopey, grumpy, sleepy)
>  **DEADLY SINS**
>  (Seven deadly sins)
>  WRATH
>  (envy, greed, gluttony, lust, pride, sloth)
>  **RAINBOW**
>  GREEN
>  ORANGE
>  (red, yellow, blue, indigo, violet)
>  **PLEIADES**
>  (Seven sisters)
>  STEROPE
>  TAYGETE
>  (maia, electra, Alcyone, celaeno,  merope)
>  **SAMURAI**
>  (Seven Samurai)
>  KATO
>  (Miyaguchi, inaba, chiaki, kimura, Shimura, mifune)
>  **MAGNIFICENT**
>  (Magnificent seven)
>  BRYNNER, BRONSON
>  (Vaughn, dexter, Coburn, Buchholz, mcqueen)
>  **TAXONOMY**
>  (7 ranks)
>  GENUS
>  (kingdom, phylum, class, order, family, species)

Comment: Beat me to it by a few minutes, drat you :-). (I was slowed up by being one E short somehow...)

Comment: Oh, I know why. There's one place where there are two equally plausible synonyms and I chose a different one from the one in the puzzle.

Comment: This is correct, well done :) But did you also note how many different letters are used for Roman numerals...? ;)

Comment: For anyone interested in the [full list of answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klQ8W.png) in position in the original diagram, here's a screenshot of my testing when creating this puzzle to satisfy your curiosity...

Comment: Note, those aren't hexagons.  They are, of course, heptagons.

Comment: @Stiv what kind of software did you use to make this? Spreadsheet, graphics editor, ...?

Comment: @cap All in MS Excel, nothing fancy :)